# JQueryMobile 1.1.1 List items not anchoring to the left

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create a simple thumbnail list, the code is pretty much copied off jqm docs pages. However, when I use the code below the button element of the list isn't anchored to the left of the list item and instead appears centered...Can anyone help me? It's driving me crazy!

I haven't got any styles in other than what is in the jquerymobile default page template

```
<div id="listDiv" class="ui-content" data-role="main">
    <div id="listInformation" data-role="content-primary">
        <ul id="swipeMeChildrenList" data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">
            <li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-btn-up-c">
                <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                    <div class="ui-btn-text">
                        <a href="index.html" class="ui-link-inherit">
                        <img src="images/album-p.jpg" class="ui-li-thumb">
                        <p>Ha</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What code do you use to generate your list from? A simple list will be specified like this:

```
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li>
            <a href="index.html">
                <img src="images/album-p.jpg" />Ha
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

jQuery Mobile will take care of adding all the necessary classes depending on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest opening a new document and using the defaults from that page, ie

```
<ul data-role="listview">
 <li><a href="index.html">
   <img src="images/album-bb.jpg" />
   <h3>Broken Bells</h3>
   <p>Broken Bells</p>
   </a></li>
</ul>
```

Then if that works, piece by piece replace the code with yours until it breaks, that should isolate the issue.

Comment: Thanks for you help...I'll give it a try and let you know how I get on.